# Magento 2 Product Images Missing On Frontend

Tags: magento2

I've been Import products via CSV Including Images.

All product data & images import sucessfully - the images were copied into their relevant directories, and show up in the back-end.

However, they don't appear on the front end, which just shows a single placeholder image. I've tried clearing the cache, reindexing, deploying static files, all to no avail.

Has anybody else had this problem and found a solution?

Edit: I tried adding a product manually through the admin interface, and it did appear on the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the media folder the right permission?

Comment: I cant confirm now but doesnt the img un the product have like a base viene,frontend viene,etc? Will check tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `validateURLScheme()` function of `\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php` as below:

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
{
        $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
        $url = parse_url($filename);
        if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

This worked for me !